# Was Klingon used in any of the Star Wars movies?

Tags: star-wars, languages, klingon-language

A comment on [this SE question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24081/are-any-of-the-alien-languages-in-star-wars-real-earth-languages/24083) stated:

> Klingon is a real Earth language, but it's only heard in the second movie and never shown printed.

I couldn't find any references to that.

**Was Klingon used in any of the Star Wars movies?**

Comment: Is that second as in empire, or second as in clones?

Comment: @NikolaiDante - you'll have to ask the original commenter, but if it was Empire, it would surely have been a more well known fact by now.

Comment: @TeamGB - "none of the makers of Star Trek were involved in the making of Star Wars" - did you LITERALLY go through the 100% full lists of everyone involved with both franchises at all times, to be able to make such a specific statement?

Comment: Klingon is not a real Earth Language it's a Fictional Language used in Star Trek. And as far as I know the makers of Star Trek were not involved in the making of Star Wars so I see no reason as to why there was Klingon in Star Wars. However due to the amount of people who worked on star wars there might be some cross over words.

Comment: @TeamGB - I was merely quoting the comment, and whether Klingon is classified as "real Earth Langiage" or not has absolutely zero bearing on the meat of the question (which was whether Klingon was used in Star Wars movies). If JohnO's phrase rubs you wrong so much, feel free to edit it out of the question.

Comment: Ohh no, it wasn't that at all. I was just commenting on what I thought it was, I was just saying it wasn't a real language and then followed up with my opinion. It wasn't anything against your question

Comment: Are you sure the commenter didn't just make a mistake Star Wars/Star Trek?

Comment: @TeamGB At what point would you consider Klingon to be non-fictional, as it is presently a spoken and written language?

Comment: Just becasue it is written and spoken does not make it a non-fiction language as another argument is the elvish in Tolkien, still a fictional language even if people can speak it. From wikipedia:
Fictional languages are intended to be the languages of a fictional world and are often designed with the intent of giving more depth and an appearance of plausibility to the fictional worlds with which they are associated
The language was made within a fictional movie/Item therefore not a non-fiction language.

Comment: @Xantec It is fictional just like the many Elvish dialects of Tolkien. Just because you can maintain a (somewhat limited) conversation in language X doesn't mean language X is a language of real-life Earth. "Fictional" here doesn't mean "not a language"; it means "a language from fiction".

Comment: Klingon is a real, but artificial language spoken by a number of people on Earth. I believe it is spoken by more people than some obscure natural languages, in fact.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[John O](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/7603/john-o) confessed [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6346246#6346246) that is [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24081/are-any-of-the-alien-languages-in-star-wars-real-earth-languages/24083#comment45588_24081) was a joke.

> I put in a flippant comment yesterday that inspired DVK to ask if klingon was spoken in the Star Wars movies.
>   I wouldn't have posted it if I thought anyone could take it serious.

So, no, Klingon was not used in any Star Wars movies.

Comment: Heh. After E.T., I'm very willing to expect stuff like that to be For Realz :)

Comment: ...and Klingon isn't a "real life" language either :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes there was. In *Star Wars Episode 3: Revenge of the Sith*. Anakin looks over to a red view screen when the senator arrives. The text symbols on the screen is Klingon. As an avid Trek fan, I couldn't miss it. It's about 1:40 minutes into the movie when he is on the volcanic planet.

Screen capture:

[image]

Upper part of the screen:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a screencap that shows this?

Comment: I took the liberty to add screen captures from the described scene to the answer (need peer review though). It definitley looks klingon-ish ...

Comment: Comparing the characters with [examples from Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Klingon_language) I'd say it may be inspired by Klingon written language, but it's not the same.

Comment: I saw this way back when, but sort of assumed it was probably Sumerian or Babylonian rather than Klingon.

Comment: All indications point to this not being Klingon text

Comment: The silhouette of the ship looks like a Klingon Bird-of-Prey heading to the upper left.

Comment: So I asked [a question about this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/212243/102999) and the conclusion is that **this is not Klingon**.