# What does this reportedly Klingon text say in Revenge of the Sith?

Tags: star-wars, star-trek, languages, klingon-language

[This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/100041/102999) has some allegedly Klingon writing. Is it Klingon? If so, what does it say?

[image: some supposedly Klingon writing]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This isn't Klingon. According to the [Font of All Knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klingon_scripts), there are three more or less commonly used scripts for Klingon.

[KLI](https://www.kli.org) **[pIqaD](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/PIqaD)** is the standard:

[image]

Earlier script efforts do not correlate with Okrand's Klingon language, and so don't appear to be in use.

Skybox pIqaD:

[image]

Mandel Script:

[image]

None of the Star Wars symbols match any of the Star Trek writing systems given for Klingon.  ST/SW Easter Eggs are apparently a thing.  This (I think obviously) is not one of them.

Comment: But what the text say?

Comment: Well, you tell us!

Comment: "Insert Coin Here"