# Why were there THREE actors for Nien Nunb? (Lando's Sullustese co-pilot in ROTJ)

Tags: star-wars

While answering [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24081/are-any-of-the-alien-languages-in-star-wars-real-earth-languages/24083), I ran into a strange fact:

[IMDB lists 3 actors](https://www.imdb.com/character/ch0036748/) for the role of Nien Nunb (Lando's Sullustese co-pilot in RotJ):

> Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi (1983)
>   Played by Richard Bonehill / Mike Quinn / Kipsang Rotich

[image: Nien Nunb]

Now, we know that Kipsang Rotich was an African student who voiced the character.

**But why are there *two more* actors listed for a three total**? (e.g. Darth Vader had one actor for voice and one for body).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to this [article](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Nien_Nunb) on Wookieepedia:

> The character Nien Nunb was realized as a puppet for his appearance in
>   *Return of the Jedi*. He was performed by Mike Quinn and Richard
>   Bonehill. Mike performed the acting in the cockpit, which was a large
>   animatronic hand puppet and Richard was the extra who was in the full
>   body suit.

See also this [interview](https://starwarsinterviews1.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/mike-quinn-interview.html) with Mike Quinn.

> They had shot some of the background walk-around Nien scenes with the extra, Richard Bonehill, already by this time.

...

> I was looking at one of the masks and was fiddling with it. Then, Phil
>   said that some scenes were coming up with this guy in the Falcon and
>   now he had to speak dialogue. The problem was that he hadn't been
>   designed and built for that. They were thinking they could put air
>   bladders in his cheeks for movement, but his mouth and eyes were
>   static and the only way around it was to cover his mouth with one of
>   those oxygen masks. That's why there are a few pictures that have
>   this. Also, you'll see the Nien scenes in the briefing room he has
>   this hanging from his neck. I put my hand inside the mouth and began
>   moving it like a hand puppet. Phil liked what he saw and suggested it
>   to George.